# Quotient of an ideal triangle in the upper half-plane by a cyclic group.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, quotient-spaces, mobius-transformation, orbifolds

Let $T$ be an ideal triangle in the Poincare upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ with the point $i$ as its "circumcenter" (by which I mean that the point $i$ is the center of symmetry of this triangle and is equidistant from the three vertices under the hyperbolic metric).

[image: An ideal triangle in the upper half-plane]

There is a natural action of the group $V_T \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ on this triangle, by counterclockwise rotations by 120 degrees permuting the vertices (given by the restriction of the rotation fractional linear transformation on $\mathbb{H}$ to $T$). This action leaves the point $i$ fixed.

Is there a description of the quotient cone $T/V_T$ and the map $\phi : T \rightarrow T/V_T$? I am interested in explicit coordinates. Presumably this question has something to do with ``orbifolds'', although I really don't know what they are.

Comment: It's rather hard to guess what you are fishing for. Ordinarily, when working with quotient maps such as $\phi : T \to T / V_T$, one simply uses a domain point $x \in T$ as a representative of its image $[x]=\phi(x) \in T / V_T$; in other words, domain points are used as (ill-defined) coordinates for points of the quotient space. The ill-definedness is not usually bothersome; it's common in manifold theory, and in orbifold theory as well. I suppose that would not be satisfactory to you. But... I would not wish to guess what *would* be satisfactory.